# How to filter Wikipedia Petscan API results using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, wikipedia-api

I am using a tool developed by wmflabs called Petscan.
This helps you scan all the articles or subcategories present under a wikipedia category.

Petscan Link : https://petscan.wmflabs.org/

I am trying to scan all the articles under the **Category:Television series**. Although I am able to get all the articles under this category but I need to apply regex to filter out articles whose title starts with either ***Lists of*** or ***List of***

There is a provision in petscan tool's > **Output** Tab, where you can specify a regular expression to do so.

[image: Output Tab and field to specify the regex]

I tried putting various regex but it somehow not able to do the trick.

Has anyone else used it to solve such a usecase. If Yes, Please let me know how to do it. I tried searching the Petscan's documentation but it does not specify the steps to do it.

Documentation : https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/PetScan

Comment: Maybe you should get in contact with the people responsible with the tool. They should (ideally) help you with your explicit problem, and also make an effort to update the documentation about the regex engine used.

Comment: All I was able to figure out from Hit & Trial was you can simply enter the title of an article that you want to match or multiple titles separated by '|' in the RegExp Filter field.
This will return only items that match the given title name.

Comment: I'm crap at regexp, but from messing around, it seems as if the only functionality provided in Petscan is for matching titles that match the string exactly. See e.g. https://petscan.wmflabs.org/?psid=15508119. It's pretty trivial to do this another way though once you've downloaded the whole list.

Comment: PetScan is written in Rust and Rust's regex library does not support lookbehinds.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions containing '+'  character are not being handled properly. You can try other special characters like '*'

I have reported the issue at https://github.com/magnusmanske/petscan_rs/issues/101